# How should I make multithreaded program that uses GPU for computation?

Tags: multithreading, opengl, gpu, vulkan, compute-shader

I am making simulation program that uses compute shaders and i ran into a problem. I am currently using OpenGL context to render GUI stuff to control and watch simulation. And I use the same context to call glDispatchCompute.

That could cause program window to freeze, because simulation might run in any UPS (like 0.1 - 10000 updates per second) and window should update in fixed FPS (display refresh rate, 60 FPS in common).

That becomes a problem, when simulation is slow and single step takes, for example 600 ms to compute. And swap buffers function waits for all compute shaders to perform, and so - FPS drops.

How can I make updates and renders independent from each other? On CPU I can just spawn second thread, but OpenGL context is not multithreaded. Should I use Vulkan for this task?

Comment: Create a separate OpenGL context for your simulation, possibly? But beware that GPUs are typically not multithreaded - *at all*. A long-running compute shader will probably block all graphics updates on the entire computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with Vulkan, there is no way to just shove a giant blob of work at the GPU and *guarantee* that later graphics work will just interrupt the GPU's processing. The most reliable way to handle this is to break your compute work up into chunks of a size that you're reasonably sure will not break your framerate and interleave them with your rendering commands.

Vulkan offers ways that *allow* GPUs to execute interruptable work, but do not *require* any particular interrupting functionality. You can create a compute queue that has the lowest possible priority and create a graphics queue with the highest priority. But even that assumes:

1. The Vulkan implementation offers multiple queues at all. Many embedded ones do not.
2. Queue priority implementations will preempt work in progress if higher-priority work is submitted. This *may* happen, but the specification offers no guarantees. [Here is some documentation about the behavior of GPUs](https://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2018/09/08/breaking-down-barriers-part-5-back-to-the-real-world/), so some of them can handle that. It's a few years old, so more recent GPUs may be even better, but it should get you started.

Overall, Vulkan *can* help, but you'll need to profile it and you'll need to have a fallback if you care about implementations that don't have enough queues to do anything.

OpenGL is of course even less useful for this, as it has no explicit queueing system at all. So breaking the work up is really the only way to ensure that the compute task doesn't starve the renderer.